# Can I incorporate XCode's text editor into my own program for text highlighting?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm trying to have a text box that has syntax highlighting.  To avoid the hassel and rework of implementing my own highlighter, is it possible to incorporate and use XCode's editor?  Similar to how QuickLook shows the contents of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

QuickLook asks a plugin how to render. Xcode's QuickLook plugin for source files uses Xcode's own library, which is not open source.

Here are [a few open source initiatives](http://cocoaobjects.com/?s=syntax) that provide syntax highlighting in Cocoa.

Comment: I tried using the Fragaria Framework, but it's set to GC-only instead of retain/release.  Is there any way to change it to retain/release?

Comment: Manually, which is potentially ugly. Or, use ARC (which requires Xcode 4.2 beta).

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 hilighting I think is now based on Clang, [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) is a new compiler technology that has many goals that traditional compilers have not tried to achieve, the feature of use to you is the compiler is not a single monolithic compiler but instead a collection of libraries, you can pitch and choose which libraries you want to use, the one you would be interested in is [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/) which takes c/c++.Objective-C source code and turns it into a symbolic tree, it then turn that into the llvm internal representation, you should be able to get the symbolic tree representation, which you can then use to hi-light source code. You can get more information about [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) from [here](http://clang.llvm.org/), one possible issue is that [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/) may only be available on Macs with Xcode installed.